# Mobile Safari crash first time page is loaded

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, mobile-safari

I've built a Javascript-heavy web app and recently tweaked it to work on iPad (it needed tweaks because it allows drawing by moving the mouse around, and onmousedown/onmousemove would not get triggered until finger release).

Now, with the tweaks, the app runs fine on Mobile Safari. I'm seeing a problem, however, where the first time I try to load the app on the iPad, it often crashes Mobile Safari. However, reopening the browser and refreshing the page loads the app perfectly and it's fully usable. After doing some research I found out that the most common cause for Mobile Safari crash is over 6MB of pictures or multiple pictures loaded through Javascript. My app only uses images for icons, so the total image size is actually very small (probably under 100KB total), my JS code, however, is 2.5MB uncompressed and 350KB compressed using gz (which is how I'm sending it to the client).

I've also read that loading images through CSS can avoid crashes due to the image size limit. I figured it was worth a try since it's also possible the crash is due to large number of images, not just total image size. After changing some of my icons to be rendered using CSS background-image property, the crash seemed to have gone. I decided to go a step further and tweak all other icons to render using CSS backgrounds as well. After changing all of my images to be rendered using CSS, all of a sudden the crash seems to be back.

Which leads me to several possible conclusions:

A.) Even the partial CSS fix I made did not actually help but somehow I got extremely lucky and saw no crash while reloading my app and restarting the iPad multiple times (then the crash is likely somewhere with my JS code or other parts of the page)

B.) I introduced some other issue when changing the rest of my icons to load through css (if that's the case, I wouldn't expect reloading the page to fix the issue, but it does)

C.) The crash is due to something in my Javascript unrelated to images (but then why does it load and work correctly after reload)

D.) iPad chokes when trying to render/uncompress that much Javascript at once (I haven't heard of this being an issue, but it's also rare to see a chunk of Javascript this big)

Does anyone know what other issues aside from 6MB image limit can cause Mobile Safari to crash the first time a page is loaded, but not the second?

If it helps, here is the link to my web app (this is the old version that loads images through JS): http://www.grafpad.com/grafpad/canvas/demo (it's written in Pyjamas, which is why there is so much generated Javascript).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that compared to your desktop the iPad is seriously underpowered. Its particularly limited in memory. I noticed right away that there were many, many script blocks on the page. Without tearing your app apart completely to try and find the culprit you might start by combining, just to see if its just dealing with that many nodes that is causing the crash.